# Move the Program Counter in Delphi Debugging

Tags: delphi, debugging, program-counter

In Visual Studio, when you're debugging with breakpoints you can change which line of code will be next to execute by dragging the execution cursor to another line; this lets you skip IF statements and the like.

I was idly wondering if there was a similar feature in Delphi anyone knew about?

I've been having a look around in the CPU window (Delphi 2006) but you only seem to be able to run through the instructions in order, not skip them.

Comment: +1 for mentioning PC instead of IP :)

Comment: Haha, thanks. I was trying to remember the right term, it's been ages since I studied compsci xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CPU View you can right-click and choose "New EIP (Ctrl + N)" to set the instruction pointer.

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I wanted. Ta! :)

Answer (score 8):

In Delphi XE you can drag the execution cursor to another line as well. Not in the CPU window, but in the editor itself.

Comment: Just tried and this works in Delphi 2010 as well. I did not know that, thanks.

Comment: You can also right-click > Debug > Set Next Statement to do the same thing.  That one has been around for ages too.

Comment: @DavidM That's also really useful, thanks! I didn't think of looking there; the editor right-click menu has so menu options that my eyes glaze over when I look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE of 2007 you can also set the execution pointer from the Debug-Contextmenu in the sourcecode.
I've tried it a few times, but its very tricky. Don't try to move the pointer outside any begin-end block or it will bite you in the @ss later